# Function scope - Defined jquery function is not working in html form(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a jquery function on an HTML form.  It is not working, I want to check that 'key' field length should not be less than 10. But it looks like, the function checkError is not called at all.

```
<form action="/search" method="get" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('key').value.length < 10) checkError();">
```

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7UwsN/

Comment: Sorry, I can't write my answer because "It is not working" (see how that was a bit too vague to do anything with?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that your form is being submitted before return false is called.  If you use the onsubmit inline you have to have false; so that it does not submit the form

Answer (score 2):

You're not really going about this correctly. You say you are trying to call a jquery function in your HTML code, but really you're doing an if condition, then maybe calling a function.

It'd be much better, and less intrusive if you move all of your processing to a javascript function. If you're using jQuery, look to setting up a `submit()` event function, then do your processing there. Returning `true` in this function then submits the form, returning `false` stops the form from processing.

This will also probably format things in such a way that will make debugging any sort of bugs much easier too...

For example:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formID").submit(function() {
        //do some processing, call other functions, whatever
        if(error)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/search" method="get" id="formID">
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work, I put this to jsfiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/7UwsN/4/

Comment: @EmmetB That would be because you used jsfiddle completely wrong.  There are several instances of invalid syntax, and you didn't even load the jquery library.  [This is how you do it correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/LUaDL/), and as it stands, this answer works fine.

Comment: yeah that solved all Daedalus, thanks. I forgot to load on jsfiddle, but on my development environment it was being lodaded. So mdub's point was right, and works, though Jace's answer works too.